# This kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu

Tags: android, linux, virtualbox, genymotion

I have problem.
Genymotion 2.6.0  + VirtualBox 4.3.12.
windows XP 32 bit.
if anyone knows a solution would be very grateful.
This kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu. 
Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU
[image]
[image]

This problem occurs with the way Android 5.x.
Android 4.4.4 - no problems.

Comment: You have chosen Other Linux 32 bit, you chould change it to 64 bit. that should do the trick

Comment: I have the same problem but I'm running a 64bit Windows 10 version and I have a x64 CPU

Comment: having same issue as well but my guest os is windows 10 (32 bit) and i have a x32 cpu  please help..stuck with it...

Answer (score 4):

Genymotion requires 64-bit hardware for the newest Android kernels. You can run a 32-bit host OS if you want, but your hardware still has to be 64-bit. Here's a section of the download page pertaining to the current Windows system requirements:

> **System Requirements**
>
> - Microsoft Windows 7, 8/8.1, 10 (32/64 bit)
> - 64 bit CPU, with VT-x or AMD-V capability, enabled in BIOS settings
> - Recent and dedicated GPU
> - 400 MB disk space
> - 2GB RAM

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle VM Box, Go to Setting->General and set Version according to your HW specs. Also you may need to enable Virtualisation option from BIOS at system startup.